# how can i subtract an hour from datetime string eg: "2017-04-20 11:46:00" and convert it back to string in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

i need to subtract an hour from a string '2017-04-20 11:46:00' and convert it back to the same format.
 I have tried below function

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2017-04-20 11:46:00');
$tosub = new DateInterval('PT01H00M');
$result =date_format($tosub,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: You can use [`DateTime::sub()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) to substract a `DateInterval` from a `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the subtract function first, and then convert to the desired format.

```
$date    =    new DateTime('2017-04-20 11:46:00');
$tosub   =    new DateInterval('PT01H00M');
$result  =    $date->sub($tosub);       // Add subtract function
echo $result->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner that will reduce your sample datetime by 1 hour:

Code:

```
$one_hour_ago=(new DateTime('2017-04-20 11:46:00'))->modify('-1 hour')->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $one_hour_ago;
```

Output:

```
2017-04-20 10:46:00
```

Comment: I like this answer best because it is a one-liner that is easy to read (compared to `DateInterval`).  @Harish I recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time = strtotime($date);
$time = $time - (60*60); //one hour
echo $new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```